# Eliminating Immediate Left Recursion

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, computation-theory

I understand that in order to eliminate an immediate left recursion from a grammar containing production of the form A⇒Aα i need to replace it by A⇒βA'and A'⇒αA/∈

Im having the following productions,i need to eliminate immediate left recursion

E⇒E+T/T

E⇒E+T/T

T⇒T*F/T

F⇒(E)/(id)

I can see that after elimination the first production becomes

E⇒TE'

E'⇒+TE'/T∈

Can somebody explain how this comes

Comment: Looks a lot like a [cs.se] question (would likely be better suited on that site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really just a matter of following the algorithm. Let's look at the general case. According to the algorithm a rule of the form:

```
A => A a1 | ... | A aN | b1 | .. | bN
```

where `A a1, ..., A aN` are nonzero left recursive sequences of terminals and nonterminals and `b1, ..., bN` are sequences of terminals and nonterminals that does not start with the terminal `A`.

The algorithm says we need to replace this by

```
A => b1 A' | ... | bN A'
A' => a1 A' | ... | aN A' | epsilon
```

Let's look at your case. Here we have

```
E => E + T | T
```

So you can think of `a1` is the sequence `+ T` since `E + T` is a left recursive sequence of terminals and nonterminals. Likewise you can think of `B1` as `T` since this is a nonleft recursive sequence. We now use this to define the new nonterminal `E` as:

```
E => b1 E'
```

And since `b1` is `T` this becomes

```
E => T E'
```

Defining `E'` we get

```
E' => a1 E' | epsilon
```

And since `a1` is `+ T` this becomes

```
E' => + T E' | epsilon
```

Thus you end up with the grammar

```
E => T E'
E' => + T E' | epsilon
```